# Why I cannot compile CPython?

Tags: macos, compilation, cpython

I'm trying to compile CPython, specifically tag  3.9.0

( `git checkout tags/v3.9.0 -b v3.9.0`)

I'm following the instructions from the book CPython Internals by Real Python.

When I tried to compile with:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include" \
 LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib" \
 ./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl) \
 --with-pydebug --enable-framework
```

I received the error: **configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet; please file a bug report**.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

This is my system:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug which is raised with the github issue [configure fails on macOS with non-Apple clang version 13 which implements --print-multiarch](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89568). As per  [*update python to `3.9.12` to fix Clang issue on macOS*](https://github.com/jessecureton/python_bazel_template/pull/5#issue-1200728658) a fix has been applied in python 3.9.12 branch.

So you have to `git checkout tags/v3.9.12 -b v3.9.12` and run the build script again to build the python version 3.9 in MacOS Monterey.